# How do you get a browser's document.body coordinates with respect to the screen?

Tags: javascript

There must be a way of finding this.
I need to figure out the coordinates of document.body with respect to a screen[image: This is as far I have got]

I need to figure out the coordinates for the question mark in the image. This will be the position of the document's body with respect to the screen. The image gives a description of the properties I could use.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

[bobbel on WebDeveloper.com](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?235723-How-to-Absolute-position-of-the-page-on-the-screen) suggests getting the width of the border by comparing the inner and outer window width, and then subtracting that from the inner-outer height difference to get the size of the window header for values you can add to screenX and screenY:

```
// compute width of borders
var borderWidth = (window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth) / 2;

// compute absolute page position
var innerScreenX = window.screenX + borderWidth;
var innerScreenY = (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight - borderWidth) + window.screenY;
```

Granted, that's not guaranteed to be correct - it's entirely possible the user has a browser with a bar at the bottom, or window decorations that are different widths on the sides / bottom - but it's an accurate, practical workaround for the top-level browser window in every default browser/windowing configuration I can think of. (Of course, this won't work for pages in an iframe.)

---

The *proper* solution for this would be to propose a spec on the whatwg mailing list to make innerScreenX and innerScreenY a standard, as described in [the discussion on Chromium issue 151983](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151983) regarding implementing an analogous value to mozInnerScreenX/Y for Chrome. It would appear that nobody has taken the time to do so, though (although there's [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/xOtoSLgaiPY) crazy proposal to implement an asynchronous API function to "calculate" it).

Answer (score 1):

As you've drawn it there,

```
x = window.screenLeft
y = window.screenTop + (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight)
```

However, I would not trust this to be consistent across all browsers.

Edit:

In firefox you can use:

```
x = window.mozInnerScreenX
y = window.mozInnerScreenY
```

There may be an equivilent in Chrome. If you only need to support these two browser, you can use custom code for each.

Comment: `window.screenLeft` is not defined. Have you tried your code?

Comment: window.outerHeight includes the footer of the browser as well. So, this wouldn't work. The position will be a little lower than the actual coordinates

Comment: @RobW This is defined in firefox and chrome. I just need a solution for these browsers.

Comment: @RobW I haven't, but I assumed these two properties existed as OP stated them. I don't think `window.screenX` will work here though, as in my browser this value is -8 at fullscreen, which doesn't make any sense (I guess the value is of the far left of the browser window rather than the content window, which I think dkulkarni wants.)

Comment: I need the coordinates of the point where the body of the browser starts.

Comment: Discussion for implementing innerScreenX in Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151983

Comment: @Oliver: That is correct. Please call the API GetWindowRect() for any maximized window and you will see that they are around 4 pixels bigger than the monitor. (the exact amount depends on the OS) So the window starts and ends outside the visible screen.